# How to check how many times one number appears in the second number?

Tags: java, random, appearance, generated

I'm new in Java and I have a task that's going like this:
Generate one number between 0-9 and a second number between 10-99.
You need to check how many times the first number appears in the second number.
(For example: The first number is 5 and the second one is 55 so the first number (5) apears 2 times in the second number (55) ).
Btw, you need to make it without arrays.

```
    package randomNumber_01;
import java.util.Random;
public class third {
public static void main (String[] args){
    Random n = new Random();
    int first = n.nextInt(9)+1;
    System.out.println("First numnber: "+first);
    int second = n.nextInt(99)+10;
    System.out.println("Second number: "+second);
    System.out.println("I stuck here");
}
}
```

Comment: Any thoughts?..

Comment: Nope :\ I don't know :(

Comment: good luck with your task! Please, come here when you will have implementation problem

Comment: We're not here to do your work for you. Did you try to solve it? What are you stuck on? Can you show us some code?

Comment: Try to break down your problem: first, generate a number between 0-9, then between 10-99. Finally, check the number of occurrences. What is blocking you?

Comment: How do I check for occurrences?

Comment: I will give you a tip, you can convert the int into a string and loop inside the characters (It's not an array so I think is valid)

Comment: @shmosel I know and I post my code, if you want you can check it :)

Comment: @aleb2000 seems legit! Thanks! I will check it!

Comment: `first` should be `n.nextInt(10)` and `second` should be `n.nextInt(90) + 10`. Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-).

Comment: As for the second step, it's a simple math equation. Figure it out on paper, then convert it to code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int count=0;
if((second%10)==first){ 
    count++;
}
if(Math.round((second/10))==first){
    count++;
}
System.out.println(first+" occurs "+count+" times in "+second);
```

Maybe this can help you ;), replace your last println by this 8 lines ;)

but as shmosel sait in comment, be carreful it's

```
int first = n.nextInt(10);

int second = n.nextInt(90)+10;
```